# What name is this text effect known by?

Tags: text

- **upgrade your career today** in the SO careers advertisement below

[image]

- the letters **PS** in the CS4 logo

[image]

How do I tell people that this is what I am talking about. Is there a commonly used name for this text affect that UI designers would use?

Comment: I don't see a SO careers advertisement.  Can you include a link or better yet, a picture?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek: I have included a picture with the question above. Try reloading the page?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's called the **letterpress** effect. Here's an article with [examples and tutorial](http://line25.com/articles/web-design-trend-showcase-letterpress-text-effect) and here's a [video lesson](http://tutcandy.com/2009/04/letterpress-emboss-text-effect/).

Answer (score 7):

I've also seen it referred to as 'embossed text'.

Answer (score 5):

Ive heard it as:

- [Cutout text](http://www.elated.com/articles/cutout-text/)
- Inner Shadow Text
- [CSS3 Inset Typography](http://sixrevisions.com/css/how-to-create-inset-typography-with-css3/)

Comment: Inner shadow is a different effect.
Cutout text is also a different effect, in the example that you link to it is used in combination with embossed text.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just called indented text.

[Affordable Website Design](http://www.affordable-website-design.me.uk/indentedtext.html) has a tutorial that describes how to create the effect in Photoshop.

Comment: Indentation means to move something over to the left as when you indent a paragraph.

Comment: @WarrenP - true. I was looking for a term that was the opposite of "emboss".